# Connection refused while attempting to connect Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using BluetoothChat example(3.1) code sample to test communications between two Samsung Galaxy Tabs. I know this has been asked many times before, but I'm still confused that when I do this:

```
BluetoothSocket mmSocket
...
mmSocket.connect();
```

This produces a connection refused. I've tried many times to pair and unpair outside and inside the program without any results. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update (Added from Answer):**

The code in both client & server is the same. These are actually two Samsung Galaxy Tabs (3.1). The error occurs while trying to connect to remote device.

```
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                //tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        //MY_UUID_SECURE);
//                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
//                           UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                 Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                 tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);                    

            } else {                      
                  Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] {int.class});
                  tmp = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(device, UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));                   

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                Log.e("Ali", "Error interacting with remote device. Here is the cause: "+ e.getMessage() );
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }
```

The listening part is as follows:

```
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;

    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            if (secure) {
                  tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            } else {

                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));                    
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Ali", "Error while connecting to device because: "+ e.getStackTrace());
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                mSocketType);
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }
```

Finally here you have the logcat:

> 

- 01-05 10:34:07.749: E/BluetoothChat(22495): +++ ON CREATE +++ 01-05
- 10:34:07.779: E/BluetoothChat(22495): ++ ON START ++ 01-05
- 10:37:41.109: E/BluetoothChat(22599): ++ ON START ++ 01-05
- 10:37:50.009: D/BluetoothChat(22599): onActivityResult -1 01-05
- 10:37:50.009: D/BluetoothChatService(22599): connect to:
- 60:D0:A9:85:AE:6A 01-05 10:37:50.009: D/BluetoothChatService(22599):
- setState() 1 -> 2 01-05 10:37:50.009: E/BluetoothChat(22599): + ON
- RESUME + 01-05 10:37:50.029: I/BluetoothChatService(22599): BEGIN
- mConnectThread SocketType:Secure 01-05 10:37:50.029:
- I/BluetoothChat(22599): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2 01-05 10:37:55.169:
- E/Ali(22599): Error interacting with remote device. Here is the cause: Host is down 01-05 10:37:55.169:
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): start 01-05 10:37:55.169:
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): setState() 2 -> 1 01-05 10:37:55.189:
- I/BluetoothChat(22599): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1 01-05 10:37:55.219:
- D/dalvikvm(22599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 171K, 4% free 6522K/6791K,paused 2ms+3ms 01-05 10:38:02.749:
- W/PhoneWindow(22599): Couldn't get audio manager 01-05 10:38:04.969:
- E/BluetoothChat(22599): - ON PAUSE   - 01-05 10:38:04.989:
- I/ApplicationPackageManager(22599): cscCountry is not German : TPH 01-05 10:38:07.059:
- D/DeviceListActivity(22599): doDiscovery() 01-05 10:38:10.609:
- D/BluetoothChat(22599):onActivityResult -1 01-05 10:38:10.609:
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): connect to: F0:08:F1:5E:51:67 01-05 10:38:10.609:
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): setState() 1 -> 2 01-05 10:38:10.609:
- E/BluetoothChat(22599): + ON RESUME + 01-05 10:38:10.609:
- I/BluetoothChatService(22599): BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Secure 01-05 10:38:10.629:
- I/BluetoothChat(22599): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 2 01-05 10:38:12.089:
- E/BluetoothChat(22599): - ON PAUSE - 01-05 10:38:12.329:
- D/CLIPBOARD(22599): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... ! 01-05 10:38:12.339:
- W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22599): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection 01-05 10:38:19.589:
- E/BluetoothChat(22599):+ ON RESUME + 01-05 10:38:20.799:
- ***E/Ali(22599): Error interacting with remote device. Here is the cause: Connection refused 01-05 10:38:20.799:***
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): start 01-05 10:38:20.799:
- D/BluetoothChatService(22599): setState() 2 -> 1 01-05 10:38:20.799:
- I/BluetoothChat(22599): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 1 01-05 10:39:23.489:
- E/BluetoothChat(22599): - ON PAUSE -

Comment: Pls post the relevant code - server and client side. Also logs with the error ..

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons to be refused:
-the wrong rfcomm port
-black list
-mistake in mac address of another device

Comment: So what's the solution then. I've tested mac address by entering manually the mac address and I understood that mac address is not the problem. How can I localize the issue?

Comment: I've even tested with reflected methods yet without result.

Comment: I'm able to pair both devices however I the device can't get connected. Please help

Comment: As Far as I know there are three types of connections, something like simple, pared and secured pared (blame me if it is not). Did you try to create the only unsecured connection? try to change listened rfcomm port to something bigger than 10,20

Comment: by the way, you can try to write simple app for win/linux to test your connection

Comment: By the way do you set android permissions to your apk?

Comment: I've used both secure & insecure methodes. Yes I've also set permissions in Manifest file. What do you mean by change "listened rfcomm port"?

Comment: @YuriyVikulov , I had the same issue and using your suggestion of an insecure connection worked like a charm form me. Thank You